# What is the most suggested Eclipse toolkits for rapid window development

Tags: eclipse

I'm looking for the most popupular eclipse plugins for rapid windowed application development.

Could you suggest the most widely used ones?

I think this question can help for a lot of people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Window Builder](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tools/download-wbpro.html) tool for Eclipse which recently became free.